# confused with 2 buttons

Tags: asp.net, html

I have 2 ASP.NET buttons in which one is been submitted with I press ENTER key in my keyboard but I need that action (Key press ENTER) to be done to the other button. How to change it?

Comment: Is it a problem of which button has the focus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [`DefaultButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx) property of your webform:

```
<form runat="server" DefaultButton="SecondButtonID">
...
</form>
```

Comment: <form runat="server" defaultbutton="YourButtonID"></form>

Answer (score 3):

You want to change the default button for the form, don't you?
If this is the case, then just set:

```
<form runat="server" defaultbutton="YourButtonID">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set the [DefaultButton property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx).